# NVL error in query Oracle

Tags: oracle, where-clause, nvl

After updating the oracle the query below starts returning strange results, it should returns column with some values but returns `null`, after some twiching with the query, found that if I change `t.event_id = d.event_id` with `t.event_id = 125162` query start working like before. Any advice?

```
SELECT LEAST (
          MAX (
             d.event_step
             - (CASE WHEN d.status IN (51, 52, 53) THEN 0 ELSE 2 END)),
          3)
          AS nextStep
  FROM x_events_step d
 WHERE d.event_id = 125162 AND d.state = 1
       AND d.event_step_id >
              NVL ( (SELECT MAX (t.event_step_id)
                       FROM x_events_step t
                      WHERE t.event_id = d.event_id AND t.state = 2),
                   0);
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle?

Comment: Shouldn't the 6th line be 'AND d.event_step_id >=' instead?

Comment: The 6th line is ok, found solution for the problem, upgrade oracle from 11.2.0.2 to 11.2.0.3 fixed.

Comment: Could you post your answer and then accept it as a solution in case anybody else comes across this in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrade from Oracle 11.2.0.2 to 11.2.0.3 the problem was resolved.